# ¿Por qué la segunda persona del singular del pretérito perfecto es la única que no acaba en "s"?

Tags: etimología, verbos, historia, tiempos-verbales, pretérito-perfecto

Veo que es un error muy frecuente en español añadir una *s* final a la segunda persona del singular del pretérito perfecto de cualquier verbo: *comistes* en lugar de *comiste*, *fuistes* en lugar de *fuiste*, etc. Sin embargo, entiendo que es algo comprensible dada la siguiente tabla:

```
SEGUNDA PERSONA DEL SINGULAR DE LOS TIEMPOS VERBALES
----------------------------------------------------

PRESENTE                 Comes/Comés
PRETÉRITO IMPERFECTO     Comías
PRETÉRITO PERFECTO       Comiste
FUTURO                   Comerás
CONDICIONAL              Comerías

PRESENTE SUBJ.           Comas
PRETÉRITO IMPERF. SUBJ.  Comieras/Comieses
FUTURO SUBJ.             Comieres

IMPERATIVO               Come/Comé
```

Si nos fijamos, todas las formas verbales a excepción de las del pretérito perfecto y el imperativo acaban en *s*. El imperativo no veo que dé problemas (tal vez salvo en el caso de *ves* en lugar de *ve*), pero el pretérito perfecto es muy dado a que se le añada esa *s* de más, tanto en la expresión hablada como en la escrita.

Mi pregunta es: ¿de dónde proviene esa forma verbal concreta, y por qué carece de *s* final cuando todos los demás tiempos la tienen? ¿Es posible que originalmente ese tiempo verbal tuviera la *s* final y se perdiera por el camino? ¿O nunca la ha tenido?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parece ser que ya desde el origen de los tiempos (es decir, [desde el latín](http://www.contraclave.es/clasicas/tema3.pdf)), el pretérito perfecto no acababa en *s* en la segunda persona del singular. De hecho la segunda persona del plural era igual que la segunda persona del singular con una *s* añadida al final. Por ejemplo, del verbo *amare* (he destacado en negrita la segunda persona del singular y del plural):

> amavi, **amavisti**, amavit, amavimus, **amavistis**, amaverunt

En la página 63 de la *[Gramática castellana](http://bdh-rd.bne.es/viewer.vm?id=0000174208&page=63)*, de Antonio de Nebrija, vemos que, **en el año 1492**, las conjugaciones del verbo *amar* en español eran (negritas mías):

> ame, **amaste**, amo, amamos, **amastes**, amaron

es decir, todas las personas eran ya como las actuales, excepto la segunda persona del plural, qué seguía siendo como la segunda persona del singular con una *s* añadida al final.

En la *[Primera gramática](https://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Gramatica_RAE_1771_reducida.pdf)* de la RAE (página 93), vemos que las formas del pretérito perfecto eran ya **en el año 1771** como son hoy (negritas mías):

> amé, **amaste**, amó, amamos, **amasteis**, amaron

Buscando en la hemeroteca digital de la BNE, aparecen [1041 resultados de *hicistes*](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/results.vm?o=&w=hicistes&f=text&t=%2Bcreation&l=600&l=700&s=0&lang=en) frente a [48811 de *hiciste*](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/results.vm?o=&w=hiciste&f=text&t=%2Bcreation&l=600&l=700&s=0&lang=en). En algunas de las obras donde aparece *hicistes*, también aparecen otros verbos conjugados en la segunda persona del singular del pretérito perfecto acabados en *-ste*.

Concluyo por tanto que **la forma sin *-s* final de la segunda persona del singular del pretérito perfecto siempre ha sido la más común** y la aceptada por las *Gramáticas* españolas, mientras que la forma incorrecta con *-s* probablemente es relativamente reciente. Aventuraría que la forma con *-s* surgió después de que la segunda persona del plural tomara la terminación *-steis*, porque antes de esto, las formas de singular y plural habrían sido indistinguibles.

Comment: Penny (2002) indica que las formas con -s en segunda persona singular aparecieron en "Old Spanish" (aunque no aporta definición ni fechas de "Old Spanish") como "cambio analógico" en imitación de todas las otras formas de segunda persona, que tenían -s. Describe la misma ambigüedad entre singular y plural a que se refiere 'wimi' en las formas anteriores del cambio de la plural de -es a -eis, causa de que la -s se suprimió. Después del cambio de la segunda, resurgió la forma con -s en singular, y continúa extremamente corriente en todas variedades del español menos la oficial ("standard").  ,